# UIButton bounds animation issue

Tags: ios, autolayout, cabasicanimation

I'm using CABasicAnimation to animate the bounds of a button. I didn't add any autolayout constraints for the button. Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

    @IBAction func onClick(sender: AnyObject) {

        //self.button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
        animation.toValue = NSValue(CGRect : CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSizeMake(self.button.bounds.size.height, self.button.bounds.size.height)))
        animation.delegate = self
        self.button.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "")

    }

    override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {

        self.button.setTitle("", forState: .Normal)
        self.button.bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSizeMake(self.button.bounds.size.height, self.button.bounds.size.height))
    }

}
```

If I comment out **setTitle("", forState: .Normal)**, everything is fine. But the button will return to it's original size immediately if the **setTitle("", forState: .Normal)** is used. I think it because the autolayout takes effect. So I set **translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints** to true. It works as I want. But I got the "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." error in my console.

How to handle this problem? I don't want to disable autolayout in my project. Although I'm using UIButton for testing, it's the same for a normal UIView.